# how would I need to change this code in order to use a data class instead of the parallel arrays it is using currently?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
shopItems = ["apple", "orange", "pear", "banana"]
itemCost = [0.99, 1.25, 1.00, 1.50] 
stock = [6, 7, 4, 5] 

def printItems(): 
    numItems = len(shopItems)
    for i in range(numItems):
        print(shopItems[i], "in stock we have", stock[i], "this item will cost", itemCost[i])

def printNumBuy():
    totalCost = 0
    for i in range(len(shopItems)):
        print(shopItems[i])
        buyItem = input("would you like to buy this item? ")
        while buyItem != "yes" or buyItem != "no":
            buyItem = input("please enter yes or no to indicate if you want to buy the item displayed ")
        if buyItem == "yes":
            amount = int(input("how many would you like to buy? "))
            while amount > stock[i]:
                amount = int(input("please do not ask for more of an item than we have in stock "))
            stock[i] = stock[i] - amount
            print("we have", stock[i], "left of that item")
            totalCost = totalCost + itemCost[i] * amount
    print(round(totalCost, 2),"\nwe have", stock, "left of each item left")
    print("thank you for your patronage have a nice day!")

printItems()
printNumBuy()
```

the part that's been giving me the most trouble is getting the code to work using data classes instead of the 3 arrays at the top of the code

Comment: Please include your code directly in the post as text rather than an image. You can format the code by enclosing it in three backticks \```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, we [can't accept images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), data or errors. Post those as text, so that others can actually copy and use your proposed solution without having to re-type everything, and your answer can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: sorry about just using an image of the code, I've inputted the code directly now hopefully that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for an item, and then a mapping of item to stock. If you use the [frozen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) parameter the instance is hashable, and then you can use it as a key in a `dict`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Item:
    name: str
    cost: float


inventory = {
    Item(name="apple", cost=0.99): 6,
    Item(name="orange", cost=1.25): 7,
    Item(name="pear", cost=1.0): 4,
    Item(name="banana", cost=1.5): 5,
}
```

Alternatively, the dataclass could have a cost and stock, and in a mapping keyed with the name.

```
@dataclass
class Stock:
    cost: float
    count: int = 0

inventory = {
    "apple": Stock(cost=0.99, count=6),
    "oragnge": Stock(cost=1.25, count=7),
    "pear": Stock(cost=1.0, count=4),
    "banana": Stock(cost=1.5, count=5),
}
```

Can you figure out how to modify your code with either of those methods?

Comment: I should be able to get the rest sorted out with that thank you for the help.